# connection issue to aws neptune in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune, neptune

i am trying to implement aws neptune in my nodejs application. i've successfully created the database, and i have written the code for connection with neptune. i am unable to connect.  following error appears:

```
ERROR Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.31.23.182:8182
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.31.23.182',
  port: 8182
}
```

i am using npm i gremline, in nodejs to establish a connection with aws neptune

following is my code for it

```
const gremlin = require("gremlin");
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;

dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(
  "wss://db-neptune-1-instance-1.crgy0cuiqvqy.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182",
  {}
);
// console.log(process.env.wws_connection_PORT);

const graph = new Graph();
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);

g.V()
  .limit(1)
  .count()
  .next()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    dc.close();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("inside catch")
    console.log("ERROR", error);
    dc.close();
  });
```

Comment: Where are you connecting from?  Neptune is only accessible from within the AWS VPC where it is hosted.

Comment: @TaylorRiggan, i am new to aws neptune. i don't have so much knowledge about it. can be please guide me a little bit. so can i do the things

Comment: Hi - we're happy to help get you going with Amazon Neptune. Are you familiar with the way Neptune networking and security is configured? If not perhaps start by looking at this documentation and see if it helps with some of the fundamentals. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-vpc.html and then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-connecting.html. Because Neptune runs inside a VPC you need to decide how you want to access it, and configure that access. It could as simple as an EC2 instance in the same VPC or from a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to connect to your AWS Neptune cluster, you should know that you cannot do it directly from your local machine.

Instead, you can use:

1. VPN Configuration: ask your system engeneer to do that (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html)
2. AWS Load Balancer: Alternatively, you can proceed with an AWS Load Balancer for connectivity (please correct me if this information is outdated).

It is because a Neptune cluster can only be created in an AWS VPC and its endpoints are only accessible within that VPC.

For more info, look up here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-connecting.html#get-started-connect-ways